# Animation with scss and react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sass

I want an animation when opening and closing my collapse, and i dont understand why it didnt work.

this is my react components

```
import {useState} from "react"
import arrow from "../../assets/arrow.png"
import "./collapses.css"


function Collapses({title, content}){
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    const toggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open)
    }


    return(
        <div className="collapse">
            <div className="collapse__title" onClick={toggle} >{title} <img src={arrow} alt="arrow"  className={`collapse__arrow ${open ? 'collapse__arrow_rotation' : ''}`}/></div>
            {open && <div className={`collapse__content ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}>{content}</div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Collapses
```

and this, is my scss

```
    .collapse__content{
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        text-align: left;
        color: #FF6060;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
        background-color: #F6F6F6;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0px;
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .collapse__content.open {
        height: auto;
      }
    .collapse__arrow {
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out
    }   
    .collapse__arrow_rotation {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

my arrow rotation working, but the height transition got no animation

Comment: Try to set `max-height: 0;` at  `collapsecontent` and `.collapse__content.open` set `max-height: 1000px;`

Comment: that was my first try and it didnt work